# Check answer, How to find Cov(x,y) and Var(2x-y)?

Tags: statistics

I have the following tableau

```
   x:   -1          0         1       total

y:  1    0         1/8        3/8      1/2
    2    3/8       1/8        0        1/2
total:   3/8       2/8        3/8       1
```

*)Find Cov(x,y) and Var(2x-y)

My work:
 I use Cov(x,y)= E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)

I have

```
 E(x)= 0
 E(Y)= 3/2
 E(X^2)= 3/4
 E(Y^2)= 5/2
```

After plug the values I have:

```
   Cov(xy)=-15/8
```

And,

```
   var(2x-y)= 4 var(x) + var(y) - 2*2 cov(xy)
   Var(2x-y)= 10.75
```

Question: I solve the exercise ok, or I have some problem. I want to check. Thanks!

Comment: Looks alright to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a  correct formula for the covariance, but then you did not compute $E(XY)$.

This is $\sum_{x,y}xy\Pr(X=x, Y=y)$.  The computation is easy, since the table has many $0$'s.  It turns out that $E(XY)=-\frac{3}{8}$. Since $E(X)=0$  the covariance is $-3/8$.

The second computation is fine in outline, but uses the wrong value for the covariance. I can verify the answer after it is corrected.

Comment: Thanks, C(xy)=-3/8 then V(2x-y)=3+1/4+3/2=19/4=4.75 , Is that correct?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that looks fine now.